# QuickFIX/n and FXALL

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to send a MarketDataRequest to FXAll FIX Server using FIX 4.3 standard. Looking at the documentation the response from the server should be as follow

```
<message name="MarketDataIncrementalRefresh" msgtype="X" msgcat="app">
  <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
  <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
    <field name="MDUpdateAction" required="Y" />
    <field name="DeleteReason" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryType" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryID" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryRefID" required="N" />
    <component name="Instrument" required="N" />
    <field name="FinancialStatus" required="N" />
    <field name="CorporateAction" required="N" />
    ... omissis ...
  </group>
</message>
```

but in the FXAll API Documentation field 55 (Instrument o Symbol) is expected just after the field MDReqID like it should be on the standard MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh message

```
<message name="MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh" msgtype="W" msgcat="app">
  <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
  <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
  ... omissis ...
</message>
```

Of course QuickFix/n engine is trapping a message MarketDataIncrementalRefresh with the field msgtype="X" and then I always have a TagNotDefinedForMessage error. How to solve this problem?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We modified our FIX43.xml file to FIX43_FXALL.xml and specific in the quickfix config file that we wanted to use that specific data dictionary (ie we used the direct path the file).

The modification looked like this:

```
<message name="MarketDataIncrementalRefresh" msgtype="X" msgcat="app">
  <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
  <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
    <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
    <field name="MDUpdateAction" required="Y" />
    <field name="MDEntryType" required="Y" />
    <field name="MDEntryID" required="Y" />
    <field name="MDEntryRefID" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryPx" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntrySize" required="N" />
    <field name="QuoteType" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryOriginator" required="N" />
    <field name="MinQty" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryPositionNo" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryDate" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryTime" required="N" />
    <field name="TickDirection" required="N" />
    <field name="MDMkt" required="N" />
    <field name="TradingSessionID" required="N" />
    <field name="TradingSessionSubID" required="N" />
    <field name="QuoteCondition" required="N" />
    <field name="TradeCondition" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntryOriginator" required="N" />
    <field name="LocationID" required="N" />
    <field name="DeskID" required="N" />
    <field name="OpenCloseSettleFlag" required="N" />
    <field name="TimeInForce" required="N" />
    <field name="ExpireDate" required="N" />
    <field name="ExpireTime" required="N" />
    <field name="ExecInst" required="N" />
    <field name="SellerDays" required="N" />
    <field name="OrderID" required="N" />
    <field name="QuoteEntryID" required="N" />
   <field name="MDEntryBuyer" required="N" />
    <field name="MDEntrySeller" required="N" />
    <field name="NumberOfOrders" required="N" />
    <field name="Scope" required="N" />
    <field name="TotalVolumeTraded" required="N" />
    <field name="TotalVolumeTradedDate" required="N" />
    <field name="TotalVolumeTradedTime" required="N" />
    <field name="NetChgPrevDay" required="N" />
    <field name="Text" required="N" />
    <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N" />
    <field name="EncodedText" required="N" />
  </group>
  <field name="FutSettDate" required="Y" />
</message>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try as soon as the market will open. It could be possible for you to send to me the whole xml file configured for FXALL?

Comment: I cannot send you the full file as we have some proprietary things in it that I am not able to send on.  I have given you what you need to solve this problem just copy it into the right place in the file and it should work fine

Comment: Have you solved the problem on demo feed about the connection which is always alive even when you stop the client? I am unable to reconnect

Comment: I don't remember having that problem, seems like that is a different question though so maybe you should post a new question